# Tracking down a write to a variable

Tags: debugging, edebug

Something `setq`s `desktop-dirname` to `nil` after my "init.el" is loaded.
I want to track down the offending code.

Just before the end of "init.el", `desktop-dirname` is correctly set.

I checked `run-hooks` by giving advise to it, but the variable was found to be set outside of `run-hooks`. But there are more hook-runners, timers, etc...

Is there a general technique to pin-point the code that writes to a variable?

Comment: Start by bisecting your init file, to see if something it is doing or loading changes this behavior (later on). Similarly, if you use a `custom-file`. And `grep` the code you load for `desktop-dirname`. And check `desktop.el` for its handling of that variable. There is no silver bullet to finding out what changed some global variable.

Comment: I have a [partially finished patch to Emacs that would let you invoke the debugger when a variable is modified](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-11/msg02454.html), I plan to update it in a couple of weeks or so.

Comment: @Drew Yeah, but that takes like O(log n) time, with not-so-cheap constant factor. Also, expressions can be dynamically generated, so static analysis like grepping is never enough. And in my case `grep` unfortunately revealed nothing... maybe I did something fancy in the past.

Comment: @npostavs Sounds great! Does your patch enable attaching arbitrary code to execute? I'm thinking of  something like "attributed variables" in Prolog, which trigger code when variables were set.

Comment: @npostavs Maybe if you could explain your patch in an answer, I will accept it. Thanks to your notification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is still under development, but in Emacs 26.1 (assuming nothing goes wrong) you will be able to do `M-x debug-watch <variable> RET` and then any change to the variable will land in the debugger with a backtrace.

You can get the patchset now, at https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24923.

> Does your patch enable attaching arbitrary code to execute?

Yes, the mechanism allows running any function when a symbol value is modified.

Comment: All this sounds too good to be true.. Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question there: [Running Elisp code when a variable is changed](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32445/running-elisp-code-when-a-variable-is-changed) that is closed as a duplicate. The feature is needed there for emacs 24.5.

You get the `backtrace` at a `setq` of a critical symbol with the following code.
Execute the code below and `(debug-setq 'desktop-dirname)` **before you load the critical section of your lisp code**.
Please note the remark of [npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs) stating that no part of the critical section of your lisp code should be byte-compiled. Be warned that there may be `auto-load`s and `require`s in that section.

```el
(defvar setq-critical-symbol)
(setq setq-critical-symbol nil)

(declare-function #'old-setq "subr" t t)

(unless (fboundp #'old-setq)
  (fset #'old-setq (symbol-function #'setq)))

(defun reset-setq ()
  "Mainly as a savior in the case of emergency."
  (interactive)
  (assert (fboundp #'old-setq)) ; should not happen with the form before the definition of `reset-setq'
  (old-setq setq-debug nil)
  (fset #'setq (symbol-function #'old-setq)))

(defun debug-setq (&optional critical-symbol)
  "Instruments `setq' such that `backtrace' is called if the `symbol-value' of a critical symbol is set via `setq'.
The critical symbol is specified by the variable `setq-critical-symbol'.
If CRITICAL-SYMBOL is non-nil `setq-critical-symbol' is set to that value (a symbol)."
  (interactive "SCritical symbol:")
  (setq setq-critical-symbol critical-symbol)
  (defmacro setq (&rest args)
    (let ((myargs (make-symbol "*myargs*")))
      `(let ((,myargs '(,@args))
             (ret (old-setq ,@args))
             debug-on-entry)
         (when setq-critical-symbol
           (while ,myargs
             (when (eq (car ,myargs) setq-critical-symbol)
               (fset #'setq (symbol-function #'old-setq)) ;; maybe that is over-cautious
               (old-setq setq-critical-symbol nil)
               (backtrace))
             (old-setq ,myargs (cddr ,myargs))))
         ret))))
```

A test demonstrating the function (can be run line-wise in the scratch-buffer):

```el
(debug-setq 'test-arg)

(defun fun-with-critical-setq ()
  (setq test-arg 0))

(fun-with-critical-setq)

(setq setq-critical-symbol nil)

(fun-with-critical-setq)
```

The first call to `fun-with-critical-setq` spits the following backtrace out:

```
  backtrace()
  (progn (fset (function setq) (symbol-function (function old-setq))) (old-setq setq-critical-symbol nil) (backtrace))
  (if (eq (car *myargs*) setq-critical-symbol) (progn (fset (function setq) (symbol-function (function old-setq))) (old-setq setq-critical-symbol nil) (backtrace)))
  (while *myargs* (if (eq (car *myargs*) setq-critical-symbol) (progn (fset (function setq) (symbol-function (function old-setq))) (old-setq setq-critical-symbol nil) (backtrace))) (old-setq *myargs* (cdr (cdr *myargs*))))
  (progn (while *myargs* (if (eq (car *myargs*) setq-critical-symbol) (progn (fset (function setq) (symbol-function (function old-setq))) (old-setq setq-critical-symbol nil) (backtrace))) (old-setq *myargs* (cdr (cdr *myargs*)))))
  (if setq-critical-symbol (progn (while *myargs* (if (eq (car *myargs*) setq-critical-symbol) (progn (fset (function setq) (symbol-function (function old-setq))) (old-setq setq-critical-symbol nil) (backtrace))) (old-setq *myargs* (cdr (cdr *myargs*))))))
  (let ((*myargs* (quote (test-arg 0))) (ret (old-setq test-arg 0)) debug-on-entry) (if setq-critical-symbol (progn (while *myargs* (if (eq (car *myargs*) setq-critical-symbol) (progn (fset (function setq) (symbol-function ...)) (old-setq setq-critical-symbol nil) (backtrace))) (old-setq *myargs* (cdr (cdr *myargs*)))))) ret)
  fun-with-critical-setq()
  eval((fun-with-critical-setq) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
```

You must ignore the overhead caused by the customized `setq` at the beginning of the backtrace.
The second call to `fun-with-critical-setq` works like the original `setq` for two reasons:

1. The customized `setq` resets its own symbol to the original version.
2. The customized `setq` works like the original version if `setq-critical-symbol` is set to `nil`.

The second reason means that if you just call `(debug-setq)` instead of `(debug-setq 'test-arg)` the customized `setq` works like the original variant until you set `setq-critical-symbol`.

Comment: That's a neat idea. You should additionally make sure to load only source files, because I think it wouldn't work for compiled code though (because the `setq` gets turned into a bytecode, so the indirection via `setq` symbol is lost).

Comment: @npostavs Thanks for the comment. I added a remark about that to the answer.